# PHP array_udiff() not working as expected

Tags: php

I'm trying to check the first three fields of an array with the first three of another array to get the  unique values. (think a primary key composed of three columns want to add rows that aren't already in the table)

this is my code so far

```
function udiffanswers($a, $b) {   
    if ($a['aid']==$b['aid'] && $a['qid']==$b['qid'] && $a['sid']==$b['sid']){
        return 0
    } else {
        return -1
    }
}
```

My one array x has values (459458,0,461541) and my other y has that same value and it is not excluding it correctly. also if y has the value (459458,1,461541) it should not exclude it because it is unique as a whole.

sample data would be `$a` has

```
  [1] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 10
        [qid] => 10
        [sid] => 10
        [freetext] => sq file
        [a] => hi
        [b] => 
        [c] => 
        [d] => 
        [e] => 
        [f] => 
        [g] => 
        [h] => 
        [i] => 
        [j] => 
        [type] => freetext
        [location] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 10
        [qid] => 1
        [sid] => 10
        [freetext] => diff
        [a] => diff
        [b] => diff
        [c] => diff
        [d] => diff
        [e] => diff
        [f] => diff
        [g] => diff
        [h] => diff
        [i] => diff
        [j] => diff
        [type] => diff
        [location] => diff
    )
```

`$b` has

```
[23] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 10
        [qid] => 2
        [sid] => 10
        [freetext] => adfadf
        [a] => adfadf
        [b] => adfadf
        [c] => adfadf
        [d] => adfadf
        [e] => adfadf
        [f] => adfadf
        [g] => adfadf
        [h] => adfadf
        [i] => adfadf
        [j] => adfadf
        [type] => adfadf
        [location] => adfadf
    )
   [50] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 10
        [qid] => 10
        [sid] => 10
        [freetext] => sq file
        [a] => hi
        [b] => 
        [c] => 
        [d] => 
        [e] => 
        [f] => 
        [g] => 
        [h] => 
        [i] => 
        [j] => 
        [type] => freetext
        [location] => 
    )
```

should return `array[2]` from `$a` but it is also returning the duplicate array

Comment: Please, post your sample data and desired result

Comment: return ($a['aid']-$b['aid']) && ($a['qid']-$b['qid'])) && ($a['sid']-$b['sid']); Would return TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: posted some sample data above

Answer (score 0):

Slice first three elements from your arrays and compare them.

```
$newA = array_splice($a,0,3);
$newB = array_splice($b,0,3);

print_r(array_diff_assoc($newA, $newB));
```